# Point pattern fill with only full points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, filling

I would like to fill a fairly complex polygon with a point pattern fill, but the border of the polygon "cuts" the circles and the result does not look as clean as I would like.

[image: dirty points]

I know it is this is how it should be, but is there a way to use only full circles/points/dots? For example, showing a black dot only if its centre is contained within the polygon (and even if part of it is outside the polygon).

Comment: Not sure this is possible (yet). If you want full points on borders then you could add another symbol layer and use **Outline: Marker line**. You would have to play around with the settings to make it look neater.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this approach, but with the following caveats:-

- it will be slower than using a point pattern fill
- it can't be rescaled if you zoom in/out - the grid pattern will be in map units
- you'll probably need to do this on a CRS in meters.

You could make a vector grid (of polygon type) with an appropriate size (say, 100m x 100m spacing) depending on the symbol spacing you want and the scale you want to print at. You could also consider using **MMQGIS Plugin > Create Grid** which also allows hexagonal grids... this will allow an 'offset' look where every other row of dots is shifted slightly.

Next, do a spatial join (join attributes by location) with the original polygon - the one you wish to fill - so that you only keep those squares which intersect your original polygon. That should give you a grid of square cells which slightly overlaps your original area.

Now, render this grid as 'centroid fill'. Centroid markers should all show completely, although it's **possible some centroids will be OUTSIDE of your fill polygon**. But it should fix the problem you have here with small interior holes clipping your symbols.

An alternative is to use a finer point spacing on your pattern fill, and smaller symbols.