# Distinct pattern symbols on the edges of overlapping polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology

I have layers with different symbol fillings `+` `-` `0`.

At the edge these symbols get cut off.

[image: example]

So I know this is possible for labels, but any way to only force full symbols?

Comment: Can you be so kind and attach an image of what is going on?

Comment: Please also add, how the symbology should look instead.

Comment: Added a reference, thanks!

Comment: are those layers points or polygons?

Comment: It's a polygon layer with a SQL filling to visualize the change in the different areas, no points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest using `'Geometry Generator'`, see image below with Geometry Generator settings:

[image: geom_gen_setting]

Here are Point Pattern Fill settings:

[image: ppf__setting]

The final output will look as following:

[image: output]

*Note:* There is one evident drawback, symbols are no more overlapping but they are sometimes partially represented. In this case I will suggest proceeding with what @Steven-Kay mentioned in [his answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/172193/99589), e.g. creating a point grid inside polygons.

---

**Refernces:**

- [Point pattern fill with only full points in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172081/point-pattern-fill-with-only-full-points-in-qgis)
- [Free and Open Source GIS Ramblings | Quick guide to geometry generator symbol layers](https://anitagraser.com/2017/04/08/a-guide-to-geometry-generator-symbol-layers/)

Comment: This is exactly how I made the fillings in the first place. but, as you can see in your example, some are partially drawn (bottom row for example). The grid-layer workaround does the job!